# how to restrict user to input same username C programming

Tags: c, authentication, passwords, system

I am currently doing Customer Loyalty System, that needs to register Username and Password. I need to restrict user from putting in the same username, but I cannot find any informtaion. Thank you in advance for helping me out.

I store everything inside text file.

```
printf("\t\t\t\t\t   Enter Your Username: ");
scanf("%s", &Username);
printf("\t\t\t\t\t   Enter Your Password: ");
scanf("%s", &Password);
//adding varable named NumofCust
NumOfCust++;
int i = 0;
//variable for boolean logic
int flag = 0;
int ch = 0;
int Points = 0;
for (i = 0; i <= NumOfCust; i++)
{
    if (strcmp(user[i].Username, Username) == 0)
    {
        flag = 1;
        break;
    }
}

if (flag == 0)
{
    strcpy(user[i].Username, Username);
    strcpy(user[i].Password, Password);
};

//opening txt file read, append, and write
FILE *readfile = fopen("CustomerRegistration.txt", "r");
if (readfile)
{
    FILE *CreateFile = fopen("CustomerRegistration.txt", "a");
    fprintf(CreateFile, "%s\n%s\n%d\n", Username, Password, Points);
    fclose(CreateFile);
    printf("\t\t\t\t\tRegistration is Successful!!!\n\t\t\t\t\t");
}

else
{
    FILE *CreateFile = fopen("CustomerRegistration.txt", "w");
    fprintf(CreateFile, "%s\n%s\n%d\n", Username, Password, Points);
    fclose(CreateFile);
    printf("\t\t\t\t\tRegistration is Successful!!!\n\t\t\t\t\t");
}
system("pause");
```

Comment: Your use of `scanf` is off - wrong arguments and no restrictions or checks. All casual data entry should be checked, and in the case of usernames and passwords, rigorously. That includes destroying the string data present before entry.

Comment: how to give restriction for user input in scanf? should I change to another type of input command? @WeatherVane anyhow, thank you for answering my question. Really appreciate it

Comment: `scanf("%s", ...)` is (nearly) **always** a *buffer overflow*. I did some effort explaining [this and other problems with `scanf()`](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html) and hope it might be helpful.

Comment: `fgets` is safer, and you can more easily tell buffer overflow. If that happens in a sensitive area like user name and password entry, you can just abort the process.

Comment: your link cannot be opened, thank you anwyay :D @FelixPalmen

Comment: @RyanVierra it must be in hot demand - I opened it earlier today, after one stall, but unable at the moment.

Comment: @RyanVierra that's bad luck now, the server seems to be down. Well, in **very** short, follow WeatherVane's advice and use `fgets()` to read input ;)

Comment: `NumOfCust++; ... for (i = 0; i <= NumOfCust; i++)`: Increasing `NumOfCust` before checking for duplicates seems to early, and `i <= NumOfCust` may be one to far, too.

Comment: ... just remember to read the man page and see in what ways `fgets` differs from `scanf` and the obsolete `gets`.

Comment: i am really thankful for your guys advice, but when I changed it to fgets(), it does not showing pointer to input my details. Sorry I am still very new in C @WeatherVane  what i put is fgets(Username, 255, readfile);

Comment: i am really thankful for your guys advice, but when I changed it to fgets(), it does not showing pointer to input my details. Sorry I am still very new in C @FelixPalmen

Comment: @RyanVierra here's [the *source*](https://github.com/Zirias/webdocs/blob/master/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.md) of the document, not as nice to read, but github also does some decent markdown parsing ... ;)

Comment: Did you read enough of the man page to discover that `fgets` retains any `newline`, providing there is room in the buffer? Going step by step, such as printing each character's *value* in the input string, will provide good feedback as to what is happening, hone your skills generally, and encourage the explorative style which can be very helpful to a programmer's progress.

Comment: thank you sir, it is really helpful :D @FelixPalmen

Comment: I will sir!!! :D. Here in my case, it is not showing any "input" line for user ._. @WeatherVane

Comment: @RyanVierra thanks for taking the time, it's a very new document and I'm still not sure whether beginners will understand it the way I wrote it. The server is back up again, so you can try now the original link ;) If you have trouble understanding something, I'm happy to get feedback, because it's really intended to *help* beginners with the task of getting input in a C program ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can organize the text file as each line is a username then when a user registers an account parse the text file for that username

```
bool isOriginalUsername(string name){
ifstream file;
file.open(//the file);
string line;
while(getline(file, line)
{
  for(int i = 0; i > //number of users; i++)
  {
    if(name == line)
    {
    return false;
    }
    getline(file, line)
  }
}
}
```

Comment: thank you for answering, but is this C programming? the commands seem unfamilliar to me. sorry ):

Comment: no this is C++ but can easily be ported to c. change ifstream to FILE*. change file.open to fopen() ect

Comment: @Abdision OP is asking for C code, please edit your answer to fit its needs, otherwise your answer might not be useful at all. Also, in C, you should check for the return of `fopen()` and in both language using `fclose()`is advised